# How to implement 15% off on first order in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to implement the 15% off your first order. And user can be guest or registered.

Please share any helpful URL or guidance or extension for Magento CE 1.9

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below code:

```
<?php
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
    $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $customer_id =  $customerData->getId();
    $_orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customer_id);                        
    $_orderCnt = $_orders->count(); //orders count
    if ($_orderCnt<1){

        // Display your discount coupon code for apply in cart page 
        // Or play with your discount code 

    }

}
```

Hope It's work for you.